# Property 'TemplatePurpose' can not be updated

Tags: sites-9, content-porter

During the import of templates with SDL Web Content Porter 9.0 into SDL Tridion Sites 9 I get the following error message:

```
2019-08-29 12:54:33 <21> [Error] Tridion.ContentManager.InvalidActionException: Property 'TemplatePurpose' can not be updated
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.TemplateBuildingBlock.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean checkInAfterSave)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<SaveItem>b__0(Boolean isRetry)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<InvokeInErrorHandler>b__0(Boolean isRetry)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.InvokeInErrorHandler[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SaveItem(IdentifiableObject item, IdentifiableObjectData deltaObject)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.UpdateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData itemData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItems(IList`1 items, Boolean specialGroupImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.Import(String packageName)
```

hotfix CM_9.0.0.14324 is already installed but this hotfix doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Related to this https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19652/dxa-2-1-upgrade-content-import-fails-due-to-templatepurpose-property